# Is a timer mandatory for drawing OPENGL ES

Tags: ios4, opengl-es, rendering, nstimer

I have a method called startAnimation:

```
-(void)startAnimation{
1:   self.animationTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/60
     target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop)
           userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
2: //[self gameLoop]
{
```

The gameLoop method is like this:

```
-(void)gameLoop{
   [self updateModel];
   [self render]
{
```

Now, a very strange thing happens. If I comment the line 1 and uncomment the line 2 in startAnimation method I will not get the objects rendered to my screen. I thought rendering might require continuously calling the gameLoop metod. But even if I set the timer to not repeat (so repats:NO) objects are drawn. It means calling the gameLoop method just once, but from an NStimer object is enough. But if I call the gameLoop method manually I do not get the objects drawn. I tried calling the method inside a loop which executes 100 times. It did not help either. Is there something special with the timers in regards with OPENGL?Sorry for the question if it's too immature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s been some time since you asked but the problem there is that the time interval is set to 1/60, which is 0 because it´s using the integer division. You should use 1.0/60.0 instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did really solve the problem though I had already forgotton about the issue. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A timer is not needed for OpenGL ES. For my drawing app the render method is called everytime the user touches the screen.

However, for games most developers use CADisplayLink to call the render or gameloop method instead of NSTimer, as CADisplayLink will call the render method each time the screen refreshes.

Setting up a CADisplayLink is done like the example below.

```
- (void)setupDisplayLink {
    //this sets up the game loop to be called once each time the screen refreshes
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLoop:)];

    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Then the gameLoop should be setup as:

```
- (void)gameLoop:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
    [self updateModel];
    [self render];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @robhasacamera for explaination, I know I should prefer CADisplayLink to NSTimer but my main question still remains unanswered. After all both NSTimer and CADisplayLink do the same thing but in different ways. You said using timers isn't mandatory in OpenGL. Then how can the case provided in the question happen?

Comment: I was a bit confused by that as well as all the timer does is call the method at a set interval. Its the same as when its called manually ([self gameLoop]). Could you provide more of your code? There might be something that not being included in your example that would explain this behavior.